# Multiple outer join using Linq with 2 joins to the same table/object. Got the SQL, need the Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to reproduce the following SQL query in Linq and need some help please.

```sql
select
   dbo.Documents.DocId, 
   dbo.Documents.ReykerAccountRef, 
   dbo.Documents.ReykerClientId DocClientID,
   CAAs.ClientId CAAClientIDCheck,
   ClientData.FullName ClientFullName, 
   CAAs.IFAId,  
   AdvisorData.FullName AdvisorFullName
from dbo.Documents
left join 
  dbo.CAAs on dbo.Documents.ReykerAccountRef = dbo.CAAs.AccountRef
left join 
  dbo.hmsProfileDatas AS ClientData
on 
  dbo.CAAs.ClientId = ClientData.ReykerClientID
left join 
  dbo.hmsProfileDatas AS AdvisorData
on 
  dbo.CAAs.IFAId = AdvisorData.ReykerClientID
```

I am trying to link to the same table twice, once for a client fullname and the other for an Advisor fullname.

The basic sql I want to produce in linq is

```sql
select table1.*,table2.*,a.Fullname, b.Fullname
from table1
left join
   table2 on table1.t2Id = table2.Id
left join
   table3 AS a 
on 
   table2.t3Id1 = table3.id1
left join
   table3 AS b 
on 
   table2.t3Id2 = table3.id2
```

So table one is joined to table2 and table2 has 2 foreign keys (t3Id1 and t3Id2) to table3 to different fields (id1 and id2).

This is what I have tried following some guidance, but it's not returning anything! What's going wrong?

```c#
        var results3 = from doc in DataContext.Documents
                       from caa
                           in DataContext.CAAs
                           .Where(c => c.AccountRef == doc.ReykerAccountRef)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
                       from cpd
                           in DataContext.hmsProfileDatas
                           .Where(pdc => pdc.ReykerClientID == caa.ClientId)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
                       from apd
                           in DataContext.hmsProfileDatas
                           .Where(pda => pda.ReykerClientID == caa.IFAId)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new DocumentInList()
                                  {
                                      DocId = doc.DocId,
                                      DocTitle = doc.DocTitle,
                                      ReykerDocumentRef = doc.ReykerDocumentRef,
                                      ReykerAccountRef = doc.ReykerAccountRef,
                                      ClientFullName = cpd.FullName,
                                      AdvisorFullName = apd.FullName,
                                      DocTypeId = doc.DocTypeId,
                                      DocTypes = doc.DocTypes,
                                      DocDate = doc.DocDate,
                                      BlobDocName = doc.BlobDocName,
                                      UploadDate = doc.UploadDate,
                                  };
```

Comment: Did you 'get' the SQL from linq query and try it in the Db

Comment: No. I am using this against SQL Azure and have not worked out how to see the SQL. There is no profiling. Just checking that now on the management panel!

Comment: but you could still test it locally on any Db, CE for example - recommended to get your things straight. With EF/CF it's easy to 'move' things around, so why not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope I understood your example correctly. Here's another simple example, that should give what you need:

```
    private class User
    {
        public int UserId;
        public string Name;
        public int GroupId;
        public int CollectionId;
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public int GroupId;
        public string Name;
    }

    public class Collection
    {
        public int CollectionId;
        public string Name;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var groups = new[] { 
            new Group { GroupId = 1, Name = "Members" },
            new Group { GroupId = 2, Name = "Administrators" } 
        };
        var collections = new[] { 
            new Collection { CollectionId = 1, Name = "Teenagers" },
            new Collection { CollectionId = 2, Name = "Seniors" } 
        };
        var users = new[] { 
            new User { UserId = 1, Name = "Ivan", GroupId = 1, CollectionId = 1 },
            new User { UserId = 2, Name = "Peter", GroupId = 1, CollectionId = 2 },
            new User { UserId = 3, Name = "Stan", GroupId = 2, CollectionId = 1 },
            new User { UserId = 4, Name = "Dan", GroupId = 2, CollectionId = 2 },
            new User { UserId = 5, Name = "Vlad", GroupId = 5, CollectionId = 2 },
            new User { UserId = 6, Name = "Greg", GroupId = 2, CollectionId = 4 },
            new User { UserId = 6, Name = "Arni", GroupId = 3, CollectionId = 3 },
        };

        var results = from u in users
                      join g in groups on u.GroupId equals g.GroupId into ug
                      from g in ug.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join c in collections on u.CollectionId equals c.CollectionId into uc
                      from c in uc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { 
                          UserName = u.Name, 
                          GroupName = g != null ? g.Name : "<No group>",
                          CollectionName = c != null ? c.Name : "<No collection>"
                      };
    }
```

It produces two join over one table to get data from other two tables.
Here's the output:

```
Ivan    Members         Teenagers
Peter   Members         Seniors
Stan    Administrators  Teenagers
Dan     Administrators  Seniors
Vlad    <No group>      Seniors
Greg    Administrators  <No collection>
Arni    <No group>      <No collection>
```

Comment: That looks great. Thanks. I didn't spot the into use before.

Comment: Finally someone who wrote a simple enough example for me to understand :)